# Как проводить тестирование метода который создает новые объекты работающие с unit of work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, юнит-тесты, тестирование

Я пытаюсь создать тест для метода который в процессе работы создает новые объекты.

```
var result = patientDoctorsSearch.Select(y => new PatientAppointmentDoctor(y.DoctorId)).ToList();
 return result;
```

проблема в том, что для создания объета используется Unit of Work

```
public class PatientAppointmentDoctor
    {
      public IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
      public Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
      public Specialization Specialization { get; set; }
        public PatientAppointmentDoctor(int doctorId)
        {
            unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
            Doctor = unitOfWork.Doctors.FindById(doctorId);
            Specialization = unitOfWork.Specializations.FindById((int)Doctor.SpecializationId);

        } 
    }
```

Для тестирования я пытался использовать moсk

```
Mock<IUnitOfWork> mock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
            Mock<EFGenericRepository<Doctor>> mock1 = new Mock<EFGenericRepository<Doctor>>();
            mock1.Setup(m => m.Get()).Returns(new List<Doctor>
               {
                 new Doctor(){DoctorId=1,DoctorName="Сергей",DoctorSurname="Аксенов",DoctorPatronymic="Валентинович",DoctorPhone="32423432" },
                 new Doctor(){DoctorId=2,DoctorName="Олег",DoctorSurname="Валов",DoctorPatronymic="Валентинович",DoctorPhone="32423432" },
                 new Doctor(){DoctorId=3,DoctorName="Ксения",DoctorSurname="Римова",DoctorPatronymic="Оксановна",DoctorPhone="43242432" }
            });
            mock.Setup(m => m.Doctors).Returns(mock1.Object);
            PatientAppointmentController controller = new PatientAppointmentController() { unitOfWork = mock.Object };
            controller.DoctorListViewModel.unitOfWork = mock.Object;

            // Действие (act)
            List<PatientAppointmentDoctor> patientAppointmentDoctors = controller.DoctorListViewModel.GetPatientAppointmentDoctorsSearch("C", "");
```

Но как фальшивый unit of work поместить в объект который создается в тестируемом методе?

Comment: Ваш класс `PatientAppointmentDoctor` должен не сам создавать `UnitOfWork`, а принимать его в конструкторе. То есть сигнатура конструктора должна выглядеть примерно так: `PatientAppointmentDoctor(int doctorId, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)`

Comment: Moq - это так называемый _ограниченный_ (constrained) изолирующий фреймворк. Есть ещё _неограниченные_ (unconstrained) isolation frameworks. Такие как TypeMock Isolator, JustMock (оба платные) и MS Fakes. Они позволяют замокать практически что угодно. То есть можно либо их применить (но это _очень_ тяжёлая артиллерия), либо сделать правильную архитектуру с инъекцией зависимостей в конструктор.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш класс `PatientAppointmentDoctor` должен не сам создавать `UnitOfWork`, а принимать его в конструкторе. То есть сигнатура конструктора должна выглядеть примерно так:

```
PatientAppointmentDoctor(int doctorId, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
```

При этом в модульном тесте появляется возможность создать мок.

---

Вы используете Moq - это так называемый ограниченный (constrained) изолирующий фреймворк. Так же как и NSubstitute, FakeItEasy.

Есть ещё неограниченные (unconstrained) isolation frameworks. Такие как TypeMock Isolator, JustMock (оба платные) и MS Fakes. Они позволяют замокать практически что угодно. То есть можно либо их применить (но это *очень* тяжёлая артиллерия), либо сделать правильную архитектуру с инъекцией зависимостей в конструктор.